# Online drawing applications

Tags: iphone, xcode

Does anybody know about Multiplayer iphone games that implement drawing and network features which allow players to guess what the opponents are drawing (like Quick Draw App.)?

Please help me with source-code or any documentation.

Comment: Who tagged this as belonging on superuser.com?  It is clearly a programming question (even if poorly worded.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't specifically for the iPhone, but [iSketch](http://www.isketch.net/i2.html) looks like what you have in mind.  Are you looking for something like that on an iPhone platform?